# Magento 2 error report add prefix in file name

Tags: magento2, php, error, reports

How i can add prefix for **error report** file name located in **`/var/report/`**?

Like : **prefix_979188230854**

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

> **Magento 2’s default error handler can be found in `{project root}\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php`. You can extend
>   this error handler with your own logic to customize the behavior.**

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Framework\App;
class ErrorHandler{
    protected $errorPhrases = [
        E_ERROR => 'Error',
        E_WARNING => 'Warning',
        E_PARSE => 'Parse Error',
        E_NOTICE => 'Notice',
        E_CORE_ERROR => 'Core Error',
        E_CORE_WARNING => 'Core Warning',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR => 'Compile Error',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'Compile Warning',
        E_USER_ERROR => 'User Error',
        E_USER_WARNING => 'User Warning',
        E_USER_NOTICE => 'User Notice',
        E_STRICT => 'Strict Notice',
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR => 'Recoverable Error',
        E_DEPRECATED => 'Deprecated Functionality',
        E_USER_DEPRECATED => 'User Deprecated Functionality',
    ];

    public function handler($errorNo, $errorStr, $errorFile, $errorLine)
    {
        if (strpos($errorStr, 'DateTimeZone::__construct') !== false) {
        // there's no way to distinguish between caught system exceptions and warnings
        return false;
    }

    $errorNo = $errorNo & error_reporting();
    if ($errorNo == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $msg = isset($this->errorPhrases[$errorNo]) ?
        $this->errorPhrases[$errorNo] : "Unknown error ({$errorNo})";
    $msg .= ": {$errorStr} in {$errorFile} on line {$errorLine}";
    throw new \Exception($msg);
}
}
```

> **To customize the log format, just make modifications in the $msg of the handler function. You can find this function under the
>   `ErrorHandler class`.**

```
$msg = isset($this->errorPhrases[$errorNo]) ?
        $this->errorPhrases[$errorNo] : "Unknown error ({$errorNo})";
$msg .= ": {$errorStr} in {$errorFile} on line {$errorLine}";
```